# Simple JApplet crashing at startup

Tags: java, macos, swing, drag-and-drop, applet

I was trying to make drag-n-drop from a JApplet to the Finder work, when I realized something very strange.

**A simple applet with just a JSlider won't run on Mac OsX!**

Here is the code (you might be done first creating a new one from scratch...):

```
package sliderApplet;

public class SliderApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SliderApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SliderApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SliderApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SliderApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jSlider1 = new javax.swing.JSlider();
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(144, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                .addComponent(jSlider1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(185, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }                                       
    private javax.swing.JSlider jSlider1;
}
```

And here the Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not implemented
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformEmbeddedFrame.isUnderMouse(CPlatformEmbeddedFrame.java:222)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CMouseInfoPeer.isWindowUnderMouse(CMouseInfoPeer.java:43)
    at java.awt.Component.findUnderMouseInWindow(Component.java:1325)
    at java.awt.Component.getMousePosition(Component.java:1377)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI.calculateThumbLocation(SynthSliderUI.java:547)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI.calculateGeometry(SynthSliderUI.java:344)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSliderUI$Handler.componentResized(BasicSliderUI.java:1496)
    at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6331)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6285)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Java version: 1.7

OsX version: 10.9.2 (Mavericks)

Safari version: 7.0.3 (9537.75.14)

The question/s is/are: are they mocking me? Do you excperience the same behavior? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: From the stacktrace, it seems some feature is not implemented on Mac OS.

Comment: @hexafraction Yes, it does. But it's a JSlider! I was addressing the problem of drag-and-drop, but if I can't get working a JSlider...